# How to read highlighted text?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I made a windows app and i want that app to read the highlighted text but i am unable to solve this problem.

Can anyone suggest me how can it read highlighted text from anywhere. Example browser and notepad etc. 
For simple strings I use

```
obj.SpeakAsync("Hello");
```

But How to read highlighted text?

I am so confused please tell me any method that solve this problem.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this and it has been asked before here on SO. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243944/how-to-get-selected-text-from-any-window-using-ui-automation-c-sharp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763563/capture-highlighted-text-from-any-window-using-c-sharp