# Get marked or selected thing and save it into created text file

Tags: c#

My question is about getting selected thing(text, image...)(not in a textbox) and use it later. I'm making a program and I wanted to enable copy/paste action(not default copy/paste), and when user presses CTRL + C the program will save selected thing into the created text file.

I already setup the background running and keyboard hook but now I dont't know how can I get selected thing into the text file.

I tried to find the answer on the internet but there is only answers for the textbox, thats why I'm asking you for a help, because I'm just starting learning c#.

Thanks for all your answers,

Cheers -DF

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include what have you tried?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you looking for a way to write content to a file from the clipboard?

Comment: No to write to create file in documents and I don't wont to use SHIFT + A instead of CTRL + C for copy and the same way for paste it.

Comment: WPF? WinForms? WebForms? MVC? Silverlight? JavaScript? Console? …?

Comment: Please add some code.. it is not clear what you want exactly..

Comment: I'm making a program and I need when user press a sort combination of key (ex: SHIFT + A) program determind that (I already setup that with keyboard hook). What I need now is that program know what Is selected or marked (text, image, app...) and when user press SHIFT + A, what is selected program save into a Created file in directory (already done). My question is how I get selected thing into the created file.

Comment: Are you sure you want to write an image in a textfile? Text isn't the problem..

Comment: If the image is selected it can only get text that is image

Answer (score 0):

You can use the StreamWriter class for that. Wherever you handle your CTRL+V event, call a function that will use a StreamWriter to create the text file using a string you could pass as a parameter:

```
void SaveStringToFile(string str)
{
   using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = 
           new   System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\test.txt"))
   {
       file.WriteLine(str);
   }
}
```

More info here: http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/ReadWriteTextFile.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: How I get What is selected into text file (ex: some text is marked and when some combination of key is pressed program detected the pressed keys (I've already setup that with keyboard hook) and save market or write marked thing into a created file)...

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question as it tackles the issue of reading highlighted text in Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763563/capture-highlighted-text-from-any-window-using-c-sharp